# Getting Error TypeError: onOk is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create conformation dialog, to conform before sending data to database, but getting this `TypeError: onOk is not a function`, onOk() is defined **ConfirmService**, please check it.

```
  app.directive('confirmDialog', function(ConfirmService) {
      return {
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: {
              eventHandler: '&ngClick'
          },
          link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.unbind("click");
            element.bind("click", function(e) {
              ConfirmService.open(attrs.confirm, scope.eventHandler, 'confirm_dialog');
            });
          }
      }
  });

  app.service('ConfirmService', function($modal) {
    var service = {};
    service.open = function (text, onOk, dialog_type) {
      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'templates/dialog.html',
        controller: 'ConfirmCtrl',
        resolve: {
          text: function () {
            return text;
          }
        }
      });

      modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        onOk();
      }, function () {
      });
    };    
    return service;
  })

  app.controller('ConfirmCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, text) {
    $scope.text = text;
    $scope.ok = function () {
      $modalInstance.close(true);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
  });
```

Comment: Not seeing the definition for onOk.  You state that it is defined in ConfirmService, but I just see an anonymous function wrapper around a call to onOk();

Comment: *please check it* ....  yup, error is correct. That function has not been defined anywhere. Nothing we can tell you other than to create the function

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown how you are using your directive, but I have a lot of doubts that this will ever work, as ngClick is a directive, not a function, and it is this that you seem to be passing as the `onOk` parameter in your service.

```
scope: {
    eventHandler: '&ngClick'
},
```